# strchr index of a value from a string

Tags: c++, function

```
char a[20]="this is";
cout<<strchr (a,'t')-a;
```

How can this  (a,'t')-a" can show the index of the first appearance of the letter t?How does it work?
Someone said that the compiler makes the sum of ASCII characters,then 
subtracts the determined character.

Comment: You can assure that someone that that was utter nonsense, for several reasons.

Comment: ... By the way, as an experiment this is not really a good one. For instance, `cout << 't' - 't';` would also "show the index of the first appearance of 't'." So repeat your line and replace the `'t'` with all of the letters (and non-letters) that occur in the sample string. For fun, include one that does *not* appear in the sample string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = strchr (a, 't')` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character `t` in the C string `a`. In your case this happens to be the same as address of the first character in `a`. This is also what the variable `a` points to.

By subtracting `x - a` your subtracting two addresses, which (thanks to [pointer arithmetic magic](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html)) will give the index of `'t'` in `a`. It's zero, because `x` and `a` are equal. Nothing to do with ASCII really.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely pointer arithmetic.

`strchr (a,'t')` returns the pointer to the character `'t'` in string `a`.
`a` hold the address of  the string.

`strchr (a,'t')`- a returns you the index  of `t` within string `a`

Example:  a has addrress 100
Address of `h` within a will be 101 ,

so you will get index 1 for character h

Answer (score 0):

strchr returns a pointer to the first found character in your string.

```
char str[] = "Some string with spaces";
char* ptr;
ptr = strchr(str, ' ');
while(ptr != 0)
{
    printf("Space on %d. place\n", ptr - str);
    ptr = strchr(ptr + 1, ' ');
}
```